# Android-How to detect on resume that my app was killed by VM?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, kill-process

In my app, when user presses HOME key and returns back to app after some time, my app gives NullPointerExceptions on various places and activities. I know that my app is being killed by OS to free some resources. Now I want that when user comes back again to app and app was previously killed, then how can I detect that my app was killed so that I can reload different resources?

Comment: have you implemented any of `onStop()` `onResume()` or `onPause()` inside your activity?

Comment: Yes. Actually I have one main activity and some other activities. User can nevigate to any activity from main. I load some load resources in main activity like some sound in soundpool and then use them in other activities. When user was in say activity C and presses the home button and comes again the resources loaded in main activity have been released and I cannot use them in activity C. I can restart activity C but what about main activity? Do you get my point?

Comment: you can place a check of null against all your static fields in onRestart()...

Comment: @KhawarRaza did u mean that you've got an activity, say A, that holds some shared data for a latter activity, say C, to use? So in your scenario, when A is been destroyed, C will get NPE? Could you save A's data to disk when its `onPause` or could you launch a service for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)` is called, check that `savedInstanceState` is not null. As stated by [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) :

> *savedInstanceState*  If the activity is being re-initialized after
>   previously being shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most
>   recently supplied in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it
>   is null.

See also [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) which is not part of the normal lifecycle but is called before the activity is killed.

Note : if the user does A ----> B ----> C --back--> B ----> C, the second time C is created the passed bundle will be `null`, as it is a new instance, not the same recreated after being killed.

Answer (score 3):

Basically: look at the picture on this page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

[image]

the various functions that are called in different situations are `onCreate`, `onStart` and `onResume`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be: implement your own `Application` and if the `onCreate()` is called, the app was killed in background

Comment: But OnCreate is also called when you first start application.