# Android OS killing process

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin

I can simulate my process being killed with CleanMaster application.

When I run CleanMaster my app is killed and when I return back to it, Application OnCreate will be called and after that OnCreate of last activity will be called.

I don't mind Android killing my application but can I make it that if android does kill it, it will start from beggining from root activity?

Comment: Are you sure you app is killed and not insert into `OnPaused` mode ?

Comment: @AsfK I put my app in background and start CleanMaster, when I return to my app Application OnCreate is called followed by OnCreate of whatever activity was showed before going to background.

Comment: Dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377668/android-how-to-detect-on-resume-that-my-app-was-killed-by-vm

Comment: @SushiHangover it's similar. What I mostly need is a way to make this situation not show to user. If I check for bundle and call finish it will exit the app and user has to enter it again. Even worse is that the whole "startup" of the app isn't that fast so user sees empty screen with background and activity name in header. And by startup I mean the time when bundle isn't null and I call finish.

Comment: You would need to control how each intent is originally created by flagging the intent(s) that you do not wish to resume from via `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` (C# = ActivityFlags.ClearTop). This of course changes the life cycle so you might need to control the OnBack yourself during 'normal' app running depending on how your app UIX flow works

Comment: @SushiHangover It's not working. I tried setting ClearTop flag but it did nothing. When os "kills" my app and I reenter it I still see empty last activity.